# javascript animation halted in ios safari webkit browser when finger is on the screen without lifting

Tags: javascript, ios, animation, webview, touch

i have a webview, that is being show in an app
there is an animation on the page, a digital timer, where i am showing the images of each digit like so 00:39, 29:39, etc

it is being animated use setInterval in javascript within the page
problem is that when i put my finger on the screen, i.e. a touch without lifting my finger
the browser halts, meaning the animation no longer animates, it stops at the place when my finger touch the screen , and it will continue animate after i lift my finger

how can i fix this?
i heard that i can use prevent default method, but wouldn't that ignore all my events on the page?

basicaly besides the timer in my webpage, i also have some stuff that user can interact with , so it is looking for the click event etc.

so i definitely want to keep that as well
please help

this happens on ios device...if i run in desktop brower, everything seems ok..not halting being observed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

found what the issue is. 
it has nothing to do with ajax request or the cpu
it is because a tiny scrolling was introduced.  apparently all the ainmation will be put on halt if you are scrolling or going to scroll.

Answer (score 1):

Just for anyone that comes across this later:
**Animations always halt in web browsers when scrolling**, which is what your web view is anticipating by the finger touch. *This will happen on desktop browsers as well*.

Answer (score 0):

Does it halt if you press anywhere or only on the counter? Try preventing clicks on the counter element. Eg..

```
$('#counter-container').click(function()
{
  e.preventDefault();

  return false;
});
```

**Edit:** Apparently this isn't an uncommon issue. When the iphone needs more CPU/Memory resources, it will halt execution of javascript. Look into using setInterval (executes javascript at a given interval until clearInterval() is called) to detect if an animation didn't complete successfully.
**Related questions:**
[User interaction sometimes screws up jQuery ajax requests in UIWebView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4691812/user-interaction-sometimes-screws-up-jquery-ajax-requests-in-uiwebview)
[AJAX constantly look for server update? Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1289489/ajax-constantly-look-for-server-update-javascript)
https://discussions.apple.com/thread/2723866?start=0&tstart=0

Comment: thanks sir, but anmation actually halts  whenever i lay my finger anywhere on the webview, not just the animation container so the solution does not work

Comment: thanks again for follow up but i am not making any ajax requests, and i am animating something simple, i don't think it will ever steal cpu resource etc. ur solution of checking if animation is done does not work, i mean, first, we don't know what is causing the animation to halt, i really doubt it is becuase of the cpu.  again, my animation resumes to animate after u lifting the finger, the animation is for a timer, say 10 seconds limit, user should do osmething within that 10 seconds, i can't re-animate it because it will give user more than 10 second to do the task, which breaks the rule.

Comment: @user1118019 what specific animation effect are you using and are you using jquery effects? if so, post the animation code and i'll test in a webview.